# What one word makes this riddle complete?

Tags: riddle

> There is an old miner named prospector Pete.
>   Who seeks the treasure that lies under feet.
>
> On a weary journey on a hungry mare,
>   he comes across a food stocked lair.
>
> But the kitchen's guarded by a nasty sheep,
>   who only wants to bite and bleat.
>
> And if he wants a meal from there,
>   he'll need to secure the beast somewhere.
>
> Just to keep things short and sweet:
>   The previous parts are obsolete.
>
> These words in order and sized with care,
>   the solution's hidden fair and square:
>
> Ram rope, ore area, pea & meat.
>   Just one thing 'til it's complete.
>
> And that one thing is simply:______

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That one thing is simply:

> EAT

because

> you can pack it all in thus:
>  ROPE
>  AREA
>  MEAT
>  reading ROPE, AREA, MEAT across and RAM, ORE, PEA, and **EAT** down.

Though I remark that

> we're awfully close to being able to get MARE in there too, which would have been nice :-).

Comment: +1 shouldn't it be rot13(rng) instead?

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant to write. [EDITED to add:] Now fixed. Sorry about that. [EDITED again to add:] In case anyone suspects me of bad faith, note that the second spoiler block, which I have not changed, already made explicit that that was the word I had in mind. The error in the first block was simply a typo.

Comment: In a district, while hoping to dine, / He sees sphagnum upon an incline. / Two vases on top / Hold cookie and chop. / He gets up and consumes with some twine.

Answer (score 5):

The one thing is simply

> (to) EAT

Because if you arrange the words as follows:

> ROPE
>  AREA
>  MEAT

The following is true:

> Reading the columns gets you RAM, ORE, and PEA, and the final missing word, EAT.